# Fill DataFrame Column depends on condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following DataFrame:

| Fruit | Color |
| --- | --- |
| Apple |  |
| Orange |  |
| Pear |  |
| Peach |  |

How can I fill the second column that depends on the 'Fruit' column value?

For instance, if the fruit is 'Apple', then the second column should be 'Red', if the fruit is Orange, then the color should be 'Orange' and so on.

I have tried to use If statment, but it doesnt work.

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Peach'], 'Color': ['','','','']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df
```

Comment: Create a dictionary and use the built-in [map method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use [**`pandas.Series.map`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) :

```
dico = {'Apple': 'Red', 'Orange': 'Orange', 'Pear': 'Green', 'Peach': 'Rose'}

df['Color'] = df['Fruit'].map(dico)
```

###### # Output :

```
print(df)

    Fruit   Color
0   Apple     Red
1  Orange  Orange
2    Pear   Green
3   Peach    Rose
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(pd.DataFrame()
 .assign(fruit=['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Peach'])
 .assign(color=lambda x: np.select([x.fruit == 'Apple',
                                    x.fruit == 'Orange',
                                    x.fruit == 'Pear',
                                    x.fruit == 'Peach'],
                                   ['Green',
                                    'Orange',
                                    'Dark green',
                                    'Pink'],
                                    default='blue')
        )                                                           
)
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use apply and a map

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Peach'], 'Color': ['','','','']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

mapa = {'Apple':'red', 'Orange':'orange', 'Pear':'green', 'Peach':'light-orange'}
df.Color = df.Fruit.apply(lambda x: mapa[x])
df
```